# Roots of linear combination with sine

Tags: trigonometry, roots, approximation

Let be $x\in [0,\pi]$ and $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, where not all are zero. I need to show that there is at most 2 real roots on $[0,\pi]$ of the function
\begin{align*}
s(x)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x\cos(x)+\alpha_2x\sin(x).
\end{align*}
As hint, I can rewrite $s$ as
\begin{align*}
s(x)=\alpha_0+\beta_0x\sin(x-\beta_1)
\end{align*}
with $\beta_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ und $\beta_1 \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Both $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are unique and calculated depending on $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

I tried to solve the expression $\beta_0x\sin(x-\beta_1)=-\alpha_0$ but I was not able to determine the roots.

I will be very thankful of your help.

Comment: Presumably $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are not all zero, correct? Otherwise $s(x)$ has infinitely many roots.

Comment: The graph of $y=x\sin(x-\beta)$ bounces up and down between the graphs of $y=x$ and $y=-x$ (why?) and crosses the $x$-axis at precisely the points $x=0,\beta,\beta\pm\pi,\beta\pm2\pi,\dots$ (why?). How often can the graph cross any given horizontal line, with $0\le x\le2\pi$?

Comment: @TheoBendit you are right, I forgot to write it down.  I  just edited it. Thank you!